# How to avoid fragment recreation when we use Jetpack Navigation with FragmentContainerView?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have an activity that has FragmentContainerView with navGraph.

After the release of Navigation Version 2.4.0-alpha01, the NavigationUI methods of onNavDestinationSelected(), BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController() and NavigationView.setupWithNavController() are now automatically save and restore the state of popped destinations, enabling support for multiple back stacks without any code changes.

Is there any workaround to get similar behaviour for FragmentContainerView

```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/homeFragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/home_navigation" />
```

Comment: You don't 'avoid recreation' as recreation is a natural part of Android that you must handle already. If you are [saving state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) as you must for handling configuration changes and process death, then your state is already saved and restored when using Navigation as well.

Answer (score 1):

FragmentContainerView already works with multiple back stacks.

There is a good overview in a [Medium article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f) by *Murat Yener* where he shows how to implement multiple back stacks to your project while using FragmentContainerView in **activity_main**.

In my case, I implemented this but multiple back stacks still didn't work. I had to remove `android:menuCategory="secondary"` from my **menu items** for multiple back stacks to work.